# Nginx subdirectory proxy, repeated subfolder name (error 404)

Tags: wordpress, nginx, proxy

I am running nginx reverse-proxy on my server, intending to navigate the request `www.example.com` to `localhost:8800/example` so I wrote this in nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    location / {
        root /;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;  
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;  
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:8880/example/;
    }
}
```

When I try to access `http://www.example.com/index.php`, the proxy works fine. However, when the request address comes with subfolders, say `http://www.example.com/wp-admin/`, my server response with 404 error and I can see from my IIS the request address is changed to `http://localhost:8880/example/example/wp-admin/`.

Any help please?